# how to assign users during a data migration in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

I know this seems like it should be a no-brainer and should work without fail, but I am getting a crazy error during a migration which is currently running during pytest initialization.

The error I am getting is:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: redshred_default_contact>": "Client.primary_contact" must be a "User" instance.
```

When i stop in the debugger on the offending line, i get the following:

```py
-> isinstance(default_user, User)
True
-> isinstance(default_user, get_user_model())
True
```

My migration is as follows:

```py
# Generated by Django 4.2.4 on 2023-09-14 18:13

from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User
from django.conf import settings

def assign_default_client(apps, schema_editor):
    Client = apps.get_model("apiserver_v2", "Client")
    client = Client.objects.get(slug="default-client")
    get_user_model().objects.update(account__client=client)

def create_default_client(apps, schema_editor):
    (default_user, _) = User.objects.get_or_create(username="default_contact")
    default_user.save()
    Client = apps.get_model("apiserver_v2", "Client")

    # BUG: this is where the bug is occurring
    client = Client.objects.create(
        name="Default Client",
        slug="default-client",
        primary_contact=default_user,
        domain="mydomain.com",
    )

    (group, _) = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="default_contact_group")
    client.new_user_group = group
    client.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ("apiserver_v2", "0026_account"),
        ("authtoken", "0003_tokenproxy"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_default_client, migrations.RunPython.noop),
        migrations.RunPython(assign_default_client, migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

My Client model is:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from shortuuid.django_fields import ShortUUIDField

class Client(models.Model):
    """A Client represents one of our clients.

    Clients are used for accounting purposes. All transactions are associated with a client.
    """
    id = ShortUUIDField(
        help_text="A string identifier for this client",
        length=22, max_length=44, primary_key=True
    )
    primary_contact = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        related_name="primary_contact_for",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    name = models.TextField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        help_text="The name of the client.",
    )
    domain = models.TextField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        help_text="New users with this email suffix will be added to this client. Leave blank to allow any. ",
    )
    new_user_group = models.ForeignKey(
        "auth.Group",
        related_name="client_for",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        help_text="The group that new users will be added to when they sign up."
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=55,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
        help_text="The slug name of this client. Label can be used to generate the slug. Will be used for RESTful lookup.",
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        related_name="clients_updated",
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        null=True,
        related_name="clients_created",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )


    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        """Print the name and primary contact"""
        return f"{self.name} <{self.primary_contact}>"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to debug without access to the project, but the issues could be that the django.contrib.auth.models.User model that you use to create `default_user` is a different model than is returned by `get_user_model`. You could quickly check if this is the case with:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

print(User is get_user_model())
```

If the result is `False`, that's the problem. If not, at least you've ruled out that possibility.

The checks you did with `isinstance` could give you a misleading result if one of the models that you checked inherits from the other. A quick example:

```py
value_error = ValueError()
isinstance(value_error, ValueError) # True
isinstance(value_error, Exception) # True, because ValueError inherits from Exception
ValueError is Exception # False
```